# Piscope resolution

Tags: pwm

I generate a carrier frequency at 38KHz and I see the output LIVE in the piscope, but the "pulse widths" are not perfect ... the pulses are more or less wide when they must all have the same width.
It is a problem of screen resolution due to a big zoom or something like that? The period is apparently rounded (because axys time is rounded). The period 38KHz is 26.3us, I see 27us for some pulses which is very very close ... but where do these imperfections come from please ? It can be a bad configuration of my carrier ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to consider the pigpio sampling rate.

By default pigpio samples every 5 µs, so a 26.3 µs square wave might be shown with a duration of 25 µs or 30 µs.  The half way point might be 10 µs or 15 µs.

If you want to get a better feel look at the time for 10 cycles.  10 cycles = 265 µs.

[image]

Compare with the same square wave when pigpio is sampling at 1 MHz.  The peaks and troughs look much more uniform.  10 cycles = 263 µs.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and your explanations.